# How to ensure a goroutine exits before main()? without using WaitGroup

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

fromm the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

var signal = make(chan struct{})

func printNumbers() {

    counter := 1
    for {
        select {
        case <-signal:
            fmt.Println("Received signal")
            // do some housekeeping
            return
        default:
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
            counter++
        }
    }
}

func main() {

    go printNumbers()

    fmt.Println("Before: active go-routines", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    close(signal)
    //time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) do some work
    fmt.Println("After: active go-routines", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    fmt.Println("Program exited")
}
```

---

Actual output is:

```
Before: active go-routines 2
After: active go-routines 2
Program exited
Received signal
```

Expected output is:

```
Before: active go-routines 2
After: active go-routines 1   
Program exited
Received signal
```

Mainly the active go-routines(after) output should be 1

How to ensure `main()` go-routine exits only after other go-routine exits?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to use a channel to wait for one goroutine as shown below.  Use a WaitGroup when waiting for multiple goroutines.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

var signal = make(chan struct{})
var done = make(chan struct{})   // closed when goroutine is done.

func printNumbers() {
    defer close(done)
    counter := 1
    for {
        select {
        case <-signal:
            fmt.Println("Received signal")
            // do some housekeeping
            return
        default:
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
            counter++
        }
    }
}

func main() {

    go printNumbers()

    fmt.Println("Before: active go-routines", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    close(signal)
    //time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) do some work
    <-done   // wait for the goroutine to be returning.
    fmt.Println("After: active go-routines", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    fmt.Println("Program exited")
}
```